# Adding product to wishlist laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm creating a functionality which allows the user to add product in wishlist, but I'm getting an error `Trying to get property of non-object` when I click the (whishlist blade), the error comes from this line `<h4>USD {{$wishlist->product->price }}</h4>` if I remove the `$product` it displays no price how do i fix this?

Wishlist Controller

```
public function index()
{
     $user = Auth::user();
     $wishlists = Wishlist::where("user_id", "=", $user->id)->orderby('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
     return view('wishlist', compact('user', 'wishlists'));
}
```

Blade

```
@if (Auth::user()->wishlist->count() )
@foreach($wishlists as $wishlist)

<h2>USD {{$wishlist->product->price }}</h2>
<h4>USD {{$wishlist->product->name }}</h4>

@endforeach
@endif
```

Wishlist.php

```
class Wishlist extends Model
{
protected $table = "wishlist";
protected $fillable=['product_id','user_id'];

public function user(){
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function product(){
   return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
}
```

User.php

```
 public function wishlist(){
    return $this->hasMany(Wishlist::class);
 }
```

Product.php

```
 public function wishlist(){
    return $this->hasMany(Wishlist::class);
 }
```

Comment: Remove `$`... `$wishlist->product->price`.

Answer (score 0):

You should first change how you check the count of wishlist, since it runs a heavy query that recovers all wishlists **then** count them. And also remove the `$` in `$product` as @lucasArbex suggested

```
@if ($wishlists->count() )
@foreach($wishlists as $wishlist)

<h2>USD {{$wishlist->product->price }}</h2>
<h4>USD {{$wishlist->product->name }}</h4>

@endforeach
@endif
```

Also change your controller and use the relation on your user

```
public function index()
{
     $user = Auth::user();

     $wishlists = $user->wishlist()->with('product')
          ->orderby('id', 'desc')
          ->paginate(10);

     return view('wishlist', compact('user', 'wishlists'));
}
```

Comment: I have tried your answer still getting the same error @N69S

Comment: @user11710915 can you post in your question more backlog of the error ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should access the `product` relation like so (removing `$`):

```
$wishlist->product->price
```

Secondly, you should eager load the wishlist's `product` using the `::with()` query builder:

```
public function index()
{
     $user = Auth::user();

     $wishlists = Wishlist::with('product')
          ->where('user_id', $user->id)
          ->orderby('id', 'desc')
          ->paginate(10);

     return view('wishlist', compact('user', 'wishlists'));
}
```

Also, if I am correct, your product relation is wrong.

Your wishlist should have many products (rather than the other way around).

In your frontend, you will need to loop through all of the wishlist's products:

```
@foreach($wishlist->products as $product)
    {{ $product->price }}
@endforeach
```

Change the relation in your `Wishlist` class to `hasMany`:

```
public function products()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting `Trying to get property of non-object` but when I dd I see the products @thisiskelvin

Comment: So should your relation not be that your wishlist has many products, rather than you wishlist belongs to a product @user11710915

Comment: If I change to `whislist has many products` then I get an error `Unknown column 'products.wishlist_id'` @thisiskelvin

Comment: @user11710915 You will need a pivot table to link up a wishlist to the wishlist's products.

Comment: Where do I put the pivot table in models? @thisiskelvin

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46994355/laravels-pivot-table-pivot-table-in-general